# Reactjs challenge output can display on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have been working smoothly with tutorial on reactjs i came to realized that i couldn't see my output because ReactDom is not define says the compiler.
ine 142:1:  'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo, { ReactComponent } from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
class Garage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Who lives in my Garage?</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Garage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

please how can this be solve

Comment: Change `import ReactDom from 'react-dom'` to `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` - it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line ReactDom to ReactDOM on the top where you import from 'react-dom'. That should work.